# C# automapper core Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have a dbo table *Records* like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE records (
    key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    value_decimal DECIMAL(10, 5) NULL,    
    value_date DATETIME NULL
)
```

EF Core maps this table into class *record* like this:

```
public class record {
    public string key {get; set;}
    public decimal? value_decimal {get; set;}
    public DateTime? value_date {get; set;}
}
```

And finally API returns `Dictionary<string, object>` like:

```
[HttpGet]
public Dictionary<string, object> getRecords() 
{
    return this.IRepository.records.ToDictionary(
                                         d => d.key, 
                                         d => (object) new { 
                                                value_date = d.value_date,
                                                value_decimal = d.value_decimal 
                                             });
}
```

This works just fine, result is used in JavaScript like `records["some_key"].value_decimal`. Perfect!

Now I need `[HttpPost]` method which receives modified dictionary from JavaScript back and maps it to EF entity back. My deepest whishes look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void saveRecords(Dictionary<string, object> payload)
{    
    var _records = this.IRepository.records.Where(w => /*some conditions*/);

    AutoMapper.Map<Dictionary<string, object>, Models.EF_Entities.record>(
                    _records, 
                    payload);

    this.IRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

Has anyone done something like this?
Thanks!

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: I see no reasons why that would not work. Also, please provide mapping configuration between `Dictionary<string, object>` and `Models.EF_Entities.record`.

Comment: What's `AutoMapper`? I'm not aware of a class named that, if it's a property, then of what type? By the way your variable and class names are _terrible_.

Comment: @FurkanKambay check out http://automapper.org/

Comment: Yeah, I know about it, that wasn't what I meant. In your code, `AutoMapper` is a property of type `Mapper` which is inside the namespace `AutoMapper`, correct? **edit:** ugh, thought you were OP. anyway, maybe it's obvious that it is?

Comment: There is no mapping configuration yet. I am unable to "pair" Dictionary<string, object> Key with property key on Record.

Comment: Try changing `Models.EF_Entities.record` to `IEnumerable<Models.EF_Entities.record>` in the AutoMapper line?

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html?highlight=dynamic

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu this works if u want to map Dictionary<string, object> to a single object. My approach is a bit more complicated. Anyway, problem has been solved with a workaround. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to * for your effort. Problem has been solved by a workaround:

```
[HttpPost]
public void saveRecords(Dictionary<string, object> payload)
{    
    var _records = this.IRepository.records.Where(w => /*some conditions*/);

    foreach (var kvp in payload)
    {
        var _record = _records.Where(w => w.key == kvp.Key).FirstOrDefault();

        if (_record != null)
        {
            AutoMapper.Map(kvp.Value, _record);
        }
    }

    this.IRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```